# Mail Composer multiple buttons

Tags: objective-c, ios6, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a question that was hoping to get some help with, I got the initial mail composer to load and work fine, but I was wondering if it is possible to say add multiple buttons that can bring up mail composer, the thing that I am trying to do in my app is give the  user the ability to email files to themselves via an attachement but is there a way to have multiple buttons that when it is clicked the mail composer will come up with that file. I hope that makes sense thanks in advance for anyone who helps

This is in my .h file

```
- (IBAction)Email:(id)sender;
```

and this is in my .m file

```
- (IBAction)Email:(id)sender
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) 
        MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mail setSubject:@"Questions or Concerns"];

    NSArray *recipient = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc@yahoo.com", nil];
    [mail setToRecipients:recipient];

    NSString *body = @"Please Send Your Feedback or any Suggestoins";
    [mail setMessageBody:body isHTML:NO];

    [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:Nil];
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Yes, but we need some code to see what your current implementation is

Comment: sorry about that I added the code I was using

Answer (score 0):

you have many options 
lets take the following senario 
you have 2 button 
but1 (tag=1, attachment is file1)
but2 (tag=2, attachment is file2)
you should connect both of buttons to the same method

```
- (IBAction)Email:(id)sender;
```

in the .m file

```
- (IBAction)Email:(id)sender
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) 
        MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mail setSubject:@"Questions or Concerns"];
 if (((UIButton *)sender).tag==1){
            // add file 1
    }
    else   if (((UIButton *)sender).tag==2){
            // add file 2 
    }
    NSArray *recipient = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc@yahoo.com", nil];
    [mail setToRecipients:recipient];

    NSString *body = @"Please Send Your Feedback or any Suggestoins";
    [mail setMessageBody:body isHTML:NO];

    [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:Nil];
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: So do I have to create two UIButtons and connect them?, and do I also need to add anything to the code you suggested, like do I add the buttons I created to the code you suggested, sorry this part of the coding is new to me

Comment: ok so I made the two UI buttons but was not sure if it was supposed to be a UI button that was weak or an IBAction that was an UI instead of an ID I did both and named them download 1 and download 2, but either way what do I do next?

Comment: when you add the button, connect them to the same iBAction method, the place the code posted in my answer in you iBAction method, dont forget to configure the tag of you buttons

Comment: when you say connect them to the same IBAction method does that mean doing a control drag to the original IBAction in my .h file for the button I created on my storyboard?, and when you say place the code you pasted in the action method and configure the tags I am not sure how to do that. Any chance you can update the code you put in your answer to kind of give me an idea of what to do?. I am really really sorry and I appreciate your patience with me I am trying to get the hang of this stuff but I am still new to this